# WPF MVVM Add textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am building WPF Application where I retrieve data from an API.

I get JSON where user have to enter value. However I have given precision for digits for example

```
{
  "beforeComma": 2,
  "afterComma": 5
}
```

With above JSON I have to dynamically add or split textbox for `_ _ , _ _ _ _ _`

I was trying to do it like that:

XAML

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InputsBeforeComma}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

VM

```
public ObservableCollection<string> InputsBeforeComma { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> InputsAfterComma { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

Constructor()
{
    InputsBeforeComma.IncreaseSize(5); // depend of JSON
    InputsAfterComma.IncreaseSize(5); // depend of JSON
}

public static ICollection<T> IncreaseSize<T>(this ICollection<T> enumerable, int size)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        enumerable.Add(default(T));
    return enumerable;
}
```

I think it is not good solution, does anyone know how to do it better?

Comment: this format `_ _ , _ _ _ _ _` looks like a `MaskedTextBox` mask

Comment: sure but its not avaible in wpf ;(

Comment: there is wpf toolkit MaskedTextBox